# How does a HTTP endpoint/URI relate to the WebAPI that it calls

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

this is a simple question, but for one new to deploying web-based applications its (at least to me) pretty fundamental but not explicitly clear in any of the examples that I have picked up from the web (they all seem to assume a certian level of knowledge).  I have a WebAPI service (as per the VS Project called PiHttpTransferService), this has an apicontroller:

```
 Namespace Controllers

Public Class PIInterfaceController
    Inherits ApiController
    <Route("{forThisTime}/{piServerName}/{piPntSrc}/{piTagFilter}")>
    <HttpGet>
    Public Function GetPiData(ByVal forThisTime As DateTime, ByVal piServerName As String, ByVal piPntSrc As String, ByVal piTagFilter As String) As String
        Dim result As String = Nothing

        'Code to do get data from a database

       Return result
    End Function


End Class
 End Namespace
```

How does this relate to requests made from a web browser.  Apologies for a question that I am sure is pretty basic knowledge to most on here, but the starting height for my bar is pretty low :-)

Kind Regards
Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you deploy your API to a server somewhere, which makes it available at a particular address/ URL.
In IIS this is a website, which will have bindings associated with it, and those bindings will have details of things like the hostname or IP address and ports which that website should response to. e.g. `https://www.example.com`

When you run/ debug your project in Visual Studio, it takes care of this for you and starts a cut-down webserver that points to your compiled code with a binding for your project that has a random port number associated with it. This is why you see things like `http://localhost:7812` in your browser.

The routes which you define on your controller methods are the paths which should be appended to the hostname to target that particular method. So from your controller above, you would access the method with a call similar to this (hostnames for example only, obviously :P ):

```
https://www.example.com/2020-01-01T00:00:00Z/servername/1/tag/
http://localhost:7812/2020-01-01T00:00:00Z/servername/1/tag/
```

This is brief, and hopefully helpful, but there are a lot of things that could be discussed here such as configuring bindings or DNS or maybe even app pools. I hope this gets to the initial crux of your question though.

Comment: Craig, thanks for your feedback.  I think I left some fundamental content out of the original post.  Does the structure of the web-site relate in any way to the VS Solution Structure.  The solution structure is as follows:

Solution: PIHttpTransferService
Project1: PIHttpTransferService (This is the WebAPI Project)

Comment: Hey Paul, I wouldn't say so in general. As a rough description, the projects in your solution will be compiled into DLL files, one per project (plus any binaries from other sources like NuGet). They will end up in a single `/bin` folder and it's those library files loaded by IIS, used with supporting content in other folders like config or HTML. All those files are published to the single website, so I wouldn't say the structure of the VS solution matters with regards to how it is exposed. That is up to the routing config/ attributes in code etc.

Comment: Craig, Ok... so I have published the service, which has generated the following content:

Folder - PIInterface
     Folder - Bin
     File - precompiledapp.config
     File - web.config
    
I am a bit puzzled as this content appears to differ from samples which I have sourced on the web :-/  The folder 'Bin' contains the compiled assemblies as you would expect along with the Roslyn folder.  Is this the correct footprint for the output I am expecting or am I missing something.